# Unable to test the background color of a footer using Cypress.io, it throws error

Tags: javascript, cypress

Unable to test the background color using Cypress.io, it throws following error while running the cypress test; CypressError: Timed out retrying: actual.equals is not a function. Installed chai-colors via `npm install chai-colors` and added following under /support/ index.js

```
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors)
```

cypress test given below:

```
describe("Background Color test", () => {
  //before(() => {
  //  cy.visit('https://sometesturl.com')
//  })
  it.only('Verify the backgroud color, this should work', () => {
     cy.visit('https://sometesturl.com')
      cy.get('#footer')
        .should('colored', '#f2e47d')
        .and('be.colored', '#f2e47d')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have tried with 'eq' and 'rgb' values corresponding to colour #f2e47d. In the following link 'brian-mann' from cypress.io affirms that says 'match' is always for regex. 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/58
Now the test got successfully asserting the background-color value in the footer area.

```
describe("Background Color test", () => {
  it.only('Verify the backgroud color, this should work', () => {
     cy.visit('https://sometesturl.com')
     cy.get('#footer')
       .should('have.css', 'background-color')
       .and('eq', 'rgb(242, 228, 125)')
  })
})
```

Comment: A more concise syntax would be `.should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(242, 228, 125)')`

Answer (score 9):

chai-colors only tests equality of different color representations.

To test that your `#footer` element has a certain background color, you will need to use the [Cypress `css()`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai-jQuery) assertion.

```
describe("Background Color test", () => {
  it.only('Verify the backgroud color, this should work', () => {
     cy.visit('https://sometesturl.com')
     cy.get('#footer')
       .should('have.css', 'background-color')
       .and('eq', 'rgb(242, 228, 125)')
  })
})
```

Comment: DavidZ: I have tried the above test code, but CypressError: 'match' requires its argument be a 'RegExp'. You passed: '#f2e47d'

Comment: David: Thank you, I have got it worked after using 'eq' and rgb values for that hex color code, posted below my answer.

Answer (score 5):

it seems you are using the wrong syntax with `chai-colors`.
Make sure you have installed it:

```sh
npm install chai-colors --save-dev
```

Then in your test use `.should('have.css', 'background-color')` instead, like:

```js
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors);

describe("Background Color test", () => {
  it.only('Verify the backgroud color, this should work', () => {
     cy.visit('https://sometesturl.com')
      cy.get('#footer')
        .should('have.css', 'background-color')
        .and('be.colored', '#f2e47d')
  });
});
```

If you get an error like `#000000` is not equal to `#f2e47d` that means your selector in the `get` doesn't have a `background-color`, so make sure you get the right element.

**Source:** Cypress recipes example [cypress-io#102](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/issues/102)

Comment: And since you are using 'chai-colors' you can also test for a CSS color name like 'pink'

Answer (score 2):

**short solution:**

```
cy.get('#footer').should('have.css', 'background-color', '#f2e47d')
```

expected `#footer` to have CSS property `background-color` with the value
`#f2e47d`.

Comment: Hum. That didn't work for me. It complains that background-color should be on rgb format instead of hexadecimal