# Test color with chai-colors plugin

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to add `chai-colors` plugin to Cypress, from [How to install the plugin "Chai Sorted" #2441](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2441)

Chris Breiding gives

```js
import chaiSorted from "chai-sorted"
chai.use(chaiSorted)
```

so for `chai-colors`

```js
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors)

cy.visit(...)
cy.get(selector)
  .should('be.colored', '#000000')
```

but this gives the error "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: actual.equals is not a function"

Comment: Did you see [Unable to test the background color of a footer using Cypress.io, it throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085409/unable-to-test-the-background-color-of-a-footer-using-cypress-io-it-throws-erro)?

Comment: I did, but frankly it's a muddle - he does not answer the question of how to use chai-colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `chai-colors` inside a `.should()` you need to pass in the color code itself (not the element)

```js
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors)

cy.visit(...)
cy.get(selector)
  .then($el => $el.css('color'))       // get color value
  .should('be.colored', '#000000')
```

---

**But note, this fails**

```js
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors)

cy.visit(...)
cy.get(selector)
  .then($el => $el.css('backgroundcolor'))       // get color value
  .should('be.colored', '#000000')
```

> expected #000000 to be the same color as #000000

because `$el.css('backgroundcolor')` returns `rgba()` instead of `rgb()`.

You would be better off importing [onecolor](https://github.com/One-com/one-color) which `chai-colors` uses internally.

Then use the converter any way you want (plus documentation is way better).

```js
import color from 'onecolor'

cy.visit(...)
cy.get(selector)
  .then($el => $el.css('backgroundcolor'))       // get color value
  .should(colorValue => {
    expect(color(colorValue).hex()).to.eq('#000000') 
  })
```